# How can I check which application opens a file by extension?

Tags: debian, command-line, defaults

I am on a debian 9 system with unknown desktop environment (ssh access). How can I find out which program is used by default to view a file with a given extension (e.g. pdf)?

Edit: Since extension is not important to the decision, the mime type of the given file can be found by using file

```
file -i file.ext
```

Comment: Extensions mean nothing in Linux, just to us humans.  The magic bits of a file though....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ask `xdg-mime`.

```
$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf
atril.desktop
```

Comment: Is that desktop agnostic?

Comment: It's desktop-agnostic as long as the desktop follows the [XDG specifications](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/).

Comment: If you are unsure which filetype, you can use  `xdg-mime query filetype path/to/file`.